Apparent contradiction in the definition of harmonic differential forms
Setting
Consider a closed Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, and the space of differential $k-$forms $\Omega^k(M)$ equipped with the exterior derivative $d$. The Riemannian metric allows also for the definition of the co-differential $\delta:\Omega^k(M)\rightarrow \Omega^{k-1}(M)$, defined by $\delta \sim \star d\star$ up to a sign which I won't consider, and a Laplacian $\Delta=d\delta+\delta d$.
A form $\omega$ is called closed if $d\omega=0$, coclosed if $\delta\omega=0$ and harmonic if $\Delta\omega=0$.
The problem
It is usually stated (see for example Nakahara, Geometry, Topology and Physics, section 7.9 theorem 7.6) that a form $\omega$ is harmonic if and only if it is closed $d\omega=0$ and coclosed $\delta\omega=0$. In particular, for 0-forms $\delta \omega=0$ trivially and the only condition for being harmonic is $d\omega=0$, i.e. the constant functions.
Consider $M=S^2$ the two-sphere. Then, there are non-constant solutions to $\Delta f=0$, where $f\in\Omega^0(S^2)$ known as the spherical harmonics $Y^\ell_m$. They are clearly harmonic functions and they are coclosed (as any function), but they are not closed, i.e. they are not constant, which enters in conflict with the condition of an harmonic form being closed and coclosed.
Where is the flaw in the previous reasoning?

The spherical harmonics are eigenfunctions of the spherical Laplacian $\Delta_{S^2}$ (which coincides with the $\Delta$ you defined for $k=0$), with eigenvalue $-\ell(\ell+1)$. In particular, they’re not harmonic for $\ell \neq 0$.
What we do have is that for $\ell=0$ (so we only have $m=0$) the function $Y^0_0$ is constant; this single function is a basis for the kernel of $\Delta$, i.e is a basis for the harmonic functions on the sphere. So, once again, the only harmonic functions on the sphere are constants.

I was puzzled for a moment too because I placed too much emphasis on “harmonic” in “spherical harmonics”.
